# onclick not loading iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events, mouseevent

Here is the JS I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loader(value, url)
{
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML=value;
    document.getElementById("display").src = url;
}var home = "HOME";

var admin = "ADMINISTARTOR";
var sales = "SALES";
var isve = "ISVE";
</script>
```

This is in the head of the document.
I have made a sidebar containing links:

```
<li><a href=<?php echo "\"/".INDEX."/sales/\"";?> onclick="loader(sales, this.href)">Sales</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=<?php echo "\"/".INDEX."/sales/move\"";?> onclick="loader(sales, this.href)">Movement</a></li>
        <li><a href=<?php echo "\"/".INDEX."/sales/cancel\"";?> onclick="loader(sales, this.href)">Cancel</a></li>
        <li><a href=<?php echo "\"/".INDEX."/sales/add\"";?> onclick="loader(sales, this.href)">Add new HW</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have a target frame as:

```
<div id='content' style='margin-left: 170px; height: 700px; width: 800px; overflow: auto;'>
    <iframe id='display' src=<?php echo "\"/".INDEX."/main/home\"";?> style='height: 650px; width: 800px;'></iframe>
</div>
```

It works when I click the top level link, Sales in my case, the relevant document gets displayed in the target frame, but as soon I navigate to submenu links, its get loaded in the whole page. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do something similar to what AJAX already does. You can adjust your loader class to use jQuery's load function. This will also allow you to get rid of the iframe if you want and just load the page into a div. In my opinion loading it into a div would be the better way to go anyways.

You'll need to reference jQuery in your pages header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you're new loader would look something like this:

```
function Loader(page) {
    $('#display').load(page + '.html');
}
```

That will load the contents of a separate HTML page into the display div based on the page name you pass it. I recommend doing some more reading on how to use jQuery and the AJAX load method. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do, but as per what I understood from the code, You want to display different iFrames on click of different links.

So if you want to do it using javascript, all the data should be loaded to the Browser and then you can hide or unhide the iframes depending on the links clicked. SO you can have different iframes for different links, and then show or hide them accordingly.

Alternatively you can go for AJAX and make a call to server to send the data for the other link clicked.

Comment: No its the same frame, which will get loaded when the links are clicked. [link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/frames-and-iframes#html5-seamless-and-sandbox-attributes) It seems forms are not allowed in the iframe, I have a form in the links. :(

Comment: well, still not get you but following can help certainly http://blog.formstack.com/2012/embed-an-iframe/